# how to check the result returned by filter in null or not and if it is null need to call a function in the controller

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller

The result of list returned by the filter **test_id** needs to be checked.If the list is null need to call a function in the controller.

```
<div class="test_list"> 
              <ul>
                <p> testID :{{test_id}}</p>-->
                 <li ng-repeat="test in test_list | filter: test_id">
                    {{test}}
                 </li>
              </ul>

         </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you check it in the filter `testId` definition?

Comment: can you little more elaborate on that..

Comment: Can you give a plunker or show the definition of your custom filter

Comment: I have a search filter on which the filter is set.As soon as I start typing in the search box the list below is populated based on the filter which i need to keep track of so that when the list gets null i need to call a function accordingly. $scope.watch is not solving my problem I guess.Thanks in advance

Comment: Now I cant, as I am sitting in the green zone secured network.Sorry for the inconvenience.I can create one more question and give the link out here if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Add a watch over the list variable in your controller and filter it programatically and call the necessary function if found null.

```
$scope.$watch("test_id", function(new_test_id) {
     //inject $filter service in your main controller
     var filtered_test_val=$filter('filter')($scope.test_val, new_test_id, false);
     if(angular.isUndefined(filtered_test_val) || filtered_test_val== null)
      {
         //call your function here.
      }     
}
```

Comment: I have a search filter on which the filter is set.As soon as I start typing in the search box the list below is populated based on the filter which i need to keep track of so that when the list gets null i need to call a function accordingly. $scope.watch is not solving my problem I guess.Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. then we add watch over the entered value in search box and calculate the filtered value accordingly. I have edited the answer. can you check if it helps ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a custome filterfor this :-)

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="data in myData | filterData:search">
    {{ data.ID }}
    {{ data.Message }}
</div>
    </div>
</div>
angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller('test',function($scope){
    $scope.myData = [
    {
       "ID" : "001",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "002",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "003",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "004",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "005",
       "Message" : " "
    },
    {
       "ID" : "006",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "007",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "007",
       "Message" : null
    }
];
})
.filter('filterData',function(){
    return function(data,search) {
        if(!search || search.length<3){
        return data;
        }
        var dataToBePushed = [];
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if(data[i].ID==search){
            dataToBePushed.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        if(dataToBePushed.length==0){
        alert("My function");
        }else{
        return dataToBePushed;
        }
    }
});
```

PS:- I checked the search after length is 3 but it may help you to clear the idea and you can manupilate it according to your requirement.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj8a9d13/)

Comment: After adding the custom filter the error shown to me in console is  "$scope.filter is not a function"  even after adding the $filter as a injector in the controller.

Comment: to be precise the error is TypeError: $scope.filter is not a function

Comment: you need to bind filter with application not with the scope like "angular.module('myapp',[])
.filter"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the built-in `filter` filter in your own custom defined filter.

```
.filter('checknull', function($filter) {
    return function(x, test) {
        var result = $filter("filter")(x, test);
        if (result.length <= 0)
            myFunc();
        return result;
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/e6d6obu0/1/)**

Comment: its showing some error in the injector..Thanks Divya]

Comment: can you check out the jsfiddle? what error are you getting and where are you trying to inject  what?